# Filter SQL Datatable in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have some code as follows:

```
  Dim view As DataView = DirectCast(SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
  view.Sort = "CreatedDateTime DESC, ID"
  view.RowFilter = "ID" = ("ID").ToString()
  Dim tb As DataTable = view.ToTable()
  SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters("ID").DefaultValue = tb.Rows(0)("ID").ToString()
  SqlDataSource1.Update()
```

I want to filter the record being edited to the ID that has been created for the record., but the view.rowfilter is not working.  There are multiple records with ID's.

Comment: Although you've not really said what exactly isn't working, I'm not completely sure exactly what you're trying to do here. What does the DataView row filter have to do with the Update command.  Why are you setting the filter to ID to the string literal "ID" (btw .ToString is pointless there) Do you actually have a record in your DB with the id of "ID"  Perhaps update your question with the exact problem and context so we know what you're trying to achive

Comment: `"ID" = ("ID").ToString()` Evaluates to a Boolean. `.RowFilter` expects a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Mary in the comments, your `Filter` is wrong. It should be a `String`, like `Sort`.

```vb
view.RowFilter = $"ID = {someIdValue}"
```

That assumes that the ID is numeric. If it's text then you need single quotes around the value.

```vb
view.RowFilter = $"ID = '{someIdValue}'"
```

Where you get the value to filter from is up to you.